# Creating multiple cumulative line graphs in Power BI with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to figure out how to create a cumulative line graph in Power BI. The problem I'm having is I have a lot of variables that need to fit in and I'm having some trouble to make it work. I've got the following columns in a table. 
Product certification
Delivery date 
Product volume

The product volume column has an associated data and certification number to each volume row. I want to create a graph that has cumulative lines for each product certification.

To create the cumulative graph by volume I've written a DAX formula that goes like this:

```
Cumulative volume =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( CONCRETE[Product Volume] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( CONCRETE ),
        CONCRETE[Delivery Date] <= MAX ( CONCRETE[Delivery Date] )
    )
)
```

However, this doesn't account for the Product certification. It only sums up the total volume to date. 
Anyone have any thoughts on how to correct this?

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Date column while filtering for ALL,

```
Cumulative volume =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( CONCRETE[Product Volume] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( CONCRETE[Delivery Date] ), 
        CONCRETE[Delivery Date] <= MAX ( CONCRETE[Delivery Date] )
    )
)
```

I hope it helps!!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response! However, I'm still missing how I might be able to filter by Product Certification, so that each individual line in the graph represents the cumulative volume for that particular certification. Does that make sense? Thanks for the support!

Comment: I think you just need to add your new measure to chart and use product certification as legend then it will breakdown volume measure by product certification.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking too but for some reason that jacks up my calculations and starts summing things way beyond what the actual numbers are. Not sure why. Do you have suggestions for a good resource to turn to for more in-depth Power BI information?

Comment: Check this out... https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/

Comment: Much appreciated!